# Проблема с показом количества починенных объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я пишу игру и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после починки, так скажем, одного генератора - он прибавляется к общему числу починенных, то-есть 1/3, но когда я перехожу к починке второго или третьего генератора, то после починки они не прибавляются к данному числу, остается также 1/3. Все комментарии в скрипте есть. Прошу помочь!!!
Скрипт -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonProverka : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    private bool hasTouchedPlayer = false;
    private bool generatorRepaired = false; // Флаг для отслеживания состояния генератора

    public Button repairButton; // Одна кнопка
    public Text percentageText; // Ссылка на текстовое поле для отображения процентов
    public Text generatorText; // Ссылка на текстовое поле для количества починенных генераторов
    public float duration = 20.0f; // Продолжительность в секундах

    private float elapsedTime = 0f;
    private bool counting = false;
    private int savedPercentage = 0;
    private int repairedGenerators = 0;

    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        SetButtonInteractable(false); // Деактивируем кнопку в начале
    }

    // Состояние кнопки
    private void SetButtonInteractable(bool isInteractable)
    {
        repairButton.interactable = isInteractable;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (counting)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (elapsedTime >= duration)
            {
                counting = false;
                savedPercentage = 100;
                percentageText.text = "100%";

                if (!generatorRepaired) // Проверяем, что генератор ещё не был починен
                {
                    generatorRepaired = true; // Устанавливаем флаг, что генератор починен
                    repairedGenerators++; // Увеличиваем количество починенных генераторов
                    generatorText.text = "Repaired Generators: " + repairedGenerators; // Обновляем текст о количестве починенных генераторов
                }
                repairButton.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Отключаем кнопку после починки
            }
            else
            {
                float percentage = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / duration); // Рассчитываем проценты от 0 до 1
                int displayPercentage = Mathf.RoundToInt(percentage * 100); // Преобразуем в проценты от 0 до 100
                percentageText.text = displayPercentage + "%"; // Обновляем текстовое поле с процентами
                savedPercentage = displayPercentage;
            }
        }

        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);

        // Проверка клика на объекте указанного слоя и прерывание счета
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundLayer))
            {
                counting = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Метод при касании триггера
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !generatorRepaired) // Проверяем, что игрок касается триггера и генератор ещё не был починен
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = true;

            // Включаем кнопку при входе в триггер
            SetButtonInteractable(true);
        }
    }

    // Метод при выходе из триггера
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = false;

            // Выключаем кнопку при выходе
            SetButtonInteractable(false);
            counting = false;
        }
    }

    // Метод для запуска счетчика
    public void StartCounting()
    {
        if (hasTouchedPlayer && !generatorRepaired) // Проверяем, что игрок касается триггера и генератор ещё не был починен
        {
            elapsedTime = savedPercentage / 100.0f * duration;
            counting = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Также, если возможно, подскажите как скрыть со сцены кнопку, я установил только отключение ее функции.

Comment: Проблема связана с тем, что после починки первого генератора, флаг generatorRepaired становится true. Этот флаг нужно сбрасывать, когда начинается починка следующего генератора

Comment: Вы правы! Добавьте ответ, дабы я мог его выбрать как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Человек, ответивший в комментарии к вопросу был прав, проблема во флажке. Я заменил его на схему - в дефолтном состоянии объект имеет тег Generator, при нажатии на кнопку и достижении 100%, его тег меняется на GeneratorRepaired.
Мой код -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonProverka : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    private bool hasTouchedPlayer = false;
    private bool counting = false;
    private float elapsedTime = 0f;
    private int savedPercentage = 0;

    // Статическая переменная для хранения количества починенных генераторов
    private static int repairedGenerators = 0;

    public Button repairButton;
    public Text percentageText;
    public Text generatorText;
    public float duration = 20.0f;
    public string repairedTag = "GeneratorRepaired";

    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        SetButtonInteractable(false);
        UpdateGeneratorText();
    }

    private void SetButtonInteractable(bool isInteractable)
    {
        repairButton.interactable = isInteractable;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (counting)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (elapsedTime >= duration)
            {
                counting = false;
                savedPercentage = 100;
                percentageText.text = "100%";

                // При достижении 100% меняем тег, увеличиваем счетчик и отключаем кнопку
                if (gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
                {
                    gameObject.tag = repairedTag;
                    repairedGenerators++;
                }

                UpdateGeneratorText();
                repairButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                float percentage = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / duration);
                int displayPercentage = Mathf.RoundToInt(percentage * 100);
                percentageText.text = displayPercentage + "%";
                savedPercentage = displayPercentage;
            }
        }

        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundLayer))
            {
                counting = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = true;
            SetButtonInteractable(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = false;
            SetButtonInteractable(false);
            counting = false;
        }
    }

    public void StartCounting()
    {
        if (hasTouchedPlayer && gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
        {
            elapsedTime = savedPercentage / 100.0f * duration;
            counting = true;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGeneratorText()
    {
        generatorText.text = "Repaired Generators: " + repairedGenerators;
    }
}
```